# Determine Regular Expression replacement string without Replacing

Tags: c#, regex

If I have some text:

```
string myText = "01001001 -This is the first line\r\n" + 
                "01001002 -This is the 2nd line\r\n" + 
                "01002003 This is the third line\r\n";
```

And I have a regular expression replacement command:

```
string searchPattern = "([0-9]{8}) -([^-])?";
string replacePatten = "$1 xx$2";
RegEx.Replace(myText,searchPatten,replacePattern);
```

This works fine, and I get the result:

```
myText = "01001001 xxThis is the first line\r\n" + 
         "01001002 xxThis is the 2nd line\r\n" + 
         "01002003 This is the third line\r\n";
```

However, what I really want is something similar to RegEx.Matches, except I also want to know what the replacement string would be. So something like:

```
Matches matches = RegEx.Matches(myText,searchPattern,replacePattern);
```

This would result in a matches collection with two results. I would know the Index and the Length of each match along what it would be replaced with:

```
matches[0].ToString() = {Index=0,Length=10,ReplacedWith="01001001 xxThis is the first line\r\n"}
matches[1].ToString() = {Index=36,Length=10,ReplacedWith="01001002 xxThis is the second line\r\n"}
```

So I want to be able to compute the replacement string without actually replacing it. I looked at MatchEvaluator Delegates, but I don't see how you can use that with replacePattern that is tied to the searchPattern.

Comment: It looks like you want `RegEx.Matches(myText,searchPatten).Cast<Match>().Select(x => $"{x.Groups[1].Value} xx{x.Groups[2].Value}")`

Comment: You are correct and your answer will work for the specific replacePattern, but I need a general solution for any searchPattern and replacePattern. Sorry, should have made the general solution requirement more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is use `Regex.Matches()` and then on every `Match` do a `Regex.Replace()`

```
var regex = new Regex(searchPattern);

var matches = regex.Matches(myText)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Match = x,
        ReplacedWith = regex.Replace(x.Value, replacePatten)
    })
    .ToArray();
```

The `Regex.Replace` internally uses the `Matches` but doesn't expose its content, nor `Regex` exposes the interpreter it uses for the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing an extension to the Match called Replacement:

```
public static string Replacement(this Match match, string replacePattern)
{
        if (replacePattern.Contains("$"))
        {
            //there is substitutes
            string result = replacePattern;
            for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
            {
                //Group[0] is the full match, so start with each captured group
                result = result.Replace("$" + i.ToString(), match.Groups[i].Value);
            }
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            //no substitutes
            return replacePattern;
        }
}
```

In my original example, I can call:

```
string newString = match.Replacement("$1 xx$2");
```

newString will then contain "01001001 xxThis is the first line\r\n". It doesn't support named groups and doesn't do any checking for escaped $, but it will work for all my current uses.